# Realtek RTL8188EUS Wireless Network Adapter problem in Xubuntu 20,04

Tags: xubuntu, internet, ethernet, realtek-wireless

Need some help... 
Nearly 20 year Ubuntu user but never encountered this kind of hassle.

Xubuntu fresh install (no dual boot).

Network manager indicates ethernet and usb wireless adapter are connecting while network monitor indicates incoming signal.
But no way to get on the web.

I would like to have one of them working in order to install lower kernel version (installed is 5.11.0-27-generic).

Does anyone see any sign of problem in the answer given by :

###### NetworkManager info

GENERAL.DEVICE: wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]> 
GENERAL.TYPE: wifi 
GENERAL.NM-TYPE: NMDeviceWifi 
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3 
GENERAL.VENDOR: Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
GENERAL.PRODUCT: RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter 
GENERAL.DRIVER: r8188eu 
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION: 5.11.0-27-generic 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION: -- 
GENERAL.HWADDR: <MAC 'wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]> 
GENERAL.MTU: 1500 
GENERAL.STATE: 100 (connected) 
GENERAL.REASON: 0 (No reason given) 
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY: 4 (full) 
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY: 4 (full) 
GENERAL.UDI: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.4/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/net/wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]> 
GENERAL.IP-IFACE: wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]> 
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE: no 
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED: yes 
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT: yes 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING: no 
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING: no 
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID: -- 
GENERAL.CONNECTION: Autelan_06F1F0  
GENERAL.CON-UUID: 409673b3-18d1-482e-a2f4-c2dd1b539282 
GENERAL.CON-PATH: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4 
GENERAL.METERED: no (guessed) 
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT: no 
CAPABILITIES.SPEED: 150 Mb/s 
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE: no 
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV: no 
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP: yes 
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP: yes 
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER: yes 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP: yes 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA: yes 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2: yes 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP: yes 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP: yes 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP: no 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC: yes 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ: yes 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ: no 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH: no 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN: no 
IP4.GATEWAY: -- 
IP4.DNS[1](http://laodan.byethost7.com/laodan-wireless-info.txt): 211.99.143.33 
IP4.DNS[2]: 58.30.131.33 
IP4.DNS[3]: 8.8.8.8 
IP4.DNS[4]: 8.8.4.4 
IP6.ADDRESS[1](http://laodan.byethost7.com/laodan-wireless-info.txt): fe80::3b20:5374:e53c:5abb/64 
IP6.GATEWAY: -- 
IP6.ROUTE[1](http://laodan.byethost7.com/laodan-wireless-info.txt): dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600 
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1 
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1](http://laodan.byethost7.com/laodan-wireless-info.txt): 409673b3-18d1-482e-a2f4-c2dd1b539282 | Autelan_06F1F0

GENERAL.DEVICE: enp2s0 
GENERAL.TYPE: ethernet 
GENERAL.NM-TYPE: NMDeviceEthernet 
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2 
GENERAL.VENDOR: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
GENERAL.PRODUCT: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller 
GENERAL.DRIVER: r8169 
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION: 5.11.0-27-generic 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION: -- 
GENERAL.HWADDR: <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF1]> 
GENERAL.MTU: 1500 
GENERAL.STATE: 30 (disconnected) 
GENERAL.REASON: 39 (Device disconnected by user or client) 
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY: 1 (none) 
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY: 1 (none) 
GENERAL.UDI: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0 
GENERAL.IP-IFACE: -- 
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE: no 
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED: yes 
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT: no 
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING: no 
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING: no 
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID: -- 
GENERAL.CONNECTION: -- 
GENERAL.CON-UUID: -- 
GENERAL.CON-PATH: -- 
GENERAL.METERED: unknown 
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT: yes 
CAPABILITIES.SPEED: 1000 Mb/s 
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE: no 
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV: no 
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP: yes 
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP: yes 
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER: yes 
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER: on 
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2 
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1](http://laodan.byethost7.com/laodan-wireless-info.txt): 8ff8620d-cd77-3c5b-b0c2-ee5decdad2c3 | Wired connection 1

Full report available [here](http://laodan.byethost7.com/laodan-wireless-info.txt) 
Thanks for any help. 
Been occupied with this problem for the whole of last week !

Comment: How are you trying to access the web?
Check other network connection commands: ping, wget, curl, traceroute6, etc. Post results.